# embeds: this.options.embeds?.map(embed => new MessageEmbed(embed).toJSON()),

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, embed

I'm trying to make my bot send a message then react with a thumbs up and down, but I keep getting that error. Here's my code:

```
supportLogChannel.send({embeds : confirmEmbed}).then(confirmEmbed => {
    confirmEmbed.react("");
    confirmEmbed.react("");
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be an array

```js
supportLogChannel.send({ embeds: [confirmEmbed] })
```